# ExtJS 4 problem, trying to do Update on deeply nested JSON Data

Tags: extjs, extjs4, crud, nested-attributes, extjs-mvc

My Json data:-

```
{
    "attributes": { 
        "list": [
        {
            "name":"attribute2",
            "value":"attribute2 value"
        }, {
            "name":"attribute1",
            "value":"attribute1 value"
        }]
    }
    "name":"name1",
    "id":1234
}
```

My Store Definition:-

```
Ext.define('Attr', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Attribute',
    autoLoad: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'data/1234',
        api: {
            update: 'newdata/1234'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'attributes.list'
        }
    }
});
```

My Model Definition:-

```
Ext.define('Attribute', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: ['name','value']
});
```

The view for displaying the above store:-

```
{
    xtype: 'grid',
    store: 'Attr',
    id: 'attrpanel',
    columns: [
    {
        header: 'Name',
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: ['name'],
        flex: 1
    }, {
        header: 'Value',
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: ['value'],
        flex: 1
    }]
}
```

**Current Situation**: I can display the data values from the Json object.

**Problem**: Whenever I call this.getAttrStore().sync() in my controller after editing the fields, I get an error.
I have searched through number of forums and realized that there seems to some problem while updating deeply nested JSON data.

I have thought of getting Peter Muller's patch but I havent really given that a shot.

Please correct me if I am wrong or if you could point me towards something useful, it would be a big help.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather Ext JS 4.0 might support reading nested JSON but it doesn't seem to support submitting that same JSON. I have this issue where Order contains OrderItems. Ext can read it fine but calling Order.Save won't include the items.

This post is by no way conclusive because the sencha team haven't replied to it but a user seems to say that it just isn't supported.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?144653-ExtJS-4-updating-deeply-nested-Json-Data

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and ended using a solution from the [Sencha forums by beachdog](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?124362-Nested-loading-nested-saving-in-new-data-package&p=780306&viewfull=1#post780306).
He uses an override to apply the associated data to the record before saving it:

```
Ext.define('custom.JsonWriterOverride', {
    override: 'Ext.data.writer.Json',

    getRecordData: function(record) {
            Ext.apply(record.data,record.getAssociatedData()); // <--
            return record.data;
    }
});
```

Then you can use the override as a requirement in your models, like the following:

```
Ext.define('My.model.Query', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: ['custom.JsonWriterOverride'], // <--
 ...
  proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'webApp/query.do',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: true
        }
    }
 });
```

IMHO, an elegant and straight-forward solution; all credits go to beachdog.

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get?
Do you get this error before or after the HTTP request?
What is the response sent by the server?

Anyway, I suggest to configure a writer for your proxy.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Bruni!
I get an error after I click on the "Save Button" which opens in a popup window. Inside the "controller" the "click save button" action event does "this.getAttrStore().sync()" which gives me a 405 Error.
The problem is that same function above when used with a non-nested Json works absolutely fine, i.e. I am able to update my Json.
Please tell me if I have been able to explain myself properly.
As far as the Writer is concerned, I configured one with the same root as reader and it also gave me the same 405 Error.
Could this be a REST services issue?

Comment: HTTP error 405 = method not allowed, so it seems something is going wrong at the server-side

Comment: There's probably a mismatch between what the server is expecting to receive, and what it's receiving. The JSON your client is sending to the server cannot be mapped to a model on the server side. Experienced the same issue cause of the nested data.